# Is there a good getting started guide for implementing custom test types for VS2010 and VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I am searching for a getting started introduction about how to implement a custom test type for VS2010 and VS2012. When googling for this information I found an example on how to do it on VS2005 and VS2008. I took the example and tried to adjust to VS2010 SDK but it seems that some types moved between namespaces and it is not that obvious.

Can anyone propose a more up to date example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new Test Runner for Visual Studio 2012 things have changed a lot again. Given that the [NUnit](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=download) and [xUnit.NET test runners](http://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/157d8cd598497a03537e892d41e7977ae1573d06#src/xunit.runner.visualstudio/VsTestRunner.cs) are open source and will provide very good examples on how to build your own test runner and discovery code.

The code samples from 2005-2010 don't really apply to 2012 any more. They might still be supported, but this is the way forward. Support for custom MsTest test types is pretty well hidden in the UI and in the TFS Build system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess NUnit and xUnit support both VS2010 and VS2012 so I can use them as an example. I will still be happy to see a full getting started article on this subject. Are you aware of one?

Comment: The VS2010 and VS2012 implementations are completely separate though. I'm not aware of sample docs, this is pretty advanced stuff. The guys from the unit testing framework have worked together with the Visual Studio Product Team to build their integration.

Comment: To anyone interested I asked on MSDN Forums and got some links to help me started. See my question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/d4eddac8-ec3a-4788-a46b-037abd8dc3c9

Comment: I found a sample on msdn arcive that demonstrates how to write a custom test type. This is the sample location: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/CustomTestTypeSample/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4057